# From nowhere dense perfect set to zero measure set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that Cantor set is nowhere dense and perfect. But if I have a nowhere dense perfect set, can I call it a Cantor set?

Also,  I already proved that a certain subset of the real line is a nowhere dense perfect set. Knowing this, what else should I consider if I want to prove that its measure is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every nonempty totally disconnected perfect compact metric space is homeomorphic to the Cantor set ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Topological_and_analytical_properties)). On the real line, having empty interior implies being totally disconnected: indeed,  every connected set is an interval, hence has nonempty interior.

For the second question: Cantor-type sets [can have positive measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). To prove that the measure is zero,  you need to find a way to cover it by intervals of total length $<\epsilon$, for any $\epsilon>0$.